# Need help spiting Azure snapshots into another tenant/subscription

Tags: azure, snapshot, azure-cli

I have a script which snapshots all my disks in a certain RG.

However when I do the snapshotting, I need them to be spat out into another tenant/subscription for a migration project!

I've got as far as snapshotting everything and spitting them into a different RG but I need to take it a step further and spit them into the same named RG but in a different tenant/sub.

My script is below:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred –SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId -ErrorAction Stop | out-null
Connect-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId | Select-AzureRmSubscription

$tagResList = Get-AzureRmResource -TagName Environment -TagValue Staging
#$tagResList = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupNameEquals testrs

#$tagRsList[0].ResourceId.Split("//")
#subscriptions
#<SubscriptionId>
#resourceGroups
#<ResourceGroupName>
#providers
#Microsoft.Compute
#virtualMachines
#<vmName>

foreach($tagRes in $tagResList) { 
        if($tagRes.ResourceId -match "Microsoft.Compute")
        {
            $vmInfo = Get-AzureRmVM sandbox207478603000 #$tagRes.ResourceId.Split("//")[4] -Name $tagRes.ResourceId.Split("//")[8]

                #Set local variables
                $location = $vmInfo.Location
                $resourceGroupName = $vmInfo.ResourceGroupName
                $timestamp = Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss

                #Snapshot name of OS data disk
                $snapshotName = $vmInfo.Name + $timestamp 

                #Create snapshot configuration
                $snapshot =  New-AzureRmSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $vmInfo.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id -Location $location  -CreateOption copy
                
                #Take snapshot
                New-AzureRmSnapshot -Snapshot $snapshot -SnapshotName $snapshotName snapshots $resourceGroupName 
                
                
                if($vmInfo.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Count -ge 1){
                        #Condition with more than one data disks
                        for($i=0; $i -le $vmInfo.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Count - 1; $i++){
                                
                            #Snapshot name of OS data disk
                            $snapshotName = $vmInfo.StorageProfile.DataDisks[$i].Name + $timestamp 
                            
                            #Create snapshot configuration
                            $snapshot =  New-AzureRmSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $vmInfo.StorageProfile.DataDisks[$i].ManagedDisk.Id -Location $location  -CreateOption copy
                            
                            #Take snapshot
                            New-AzureRmSnapshot -Snapshot $snapshot -SnapshotName $snapshotName snapshots $ResourceGroupName
                        }
                    }
                else{
                        Write-Host $vmInfo.Name + " doesn't have any additional data disk."
                }
        }
        else{
            $tagRes.ResourceId + " is not a compute instance"
        }
}

$tagRgList = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Tag @{ Environment = "Staging" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can save snapshot in another tenant in one command as you'd need to be authenticated there.
I would suggest using [azcopy tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy) to move snapshot files between storage accounts

#######################################

Reviewed your comment and found that indeed you can't use azcopy on vm images.

But you may create access to the snapshot

```
#Generate the SAS for the snapshot 
$sas = Grant-AzSnapshotAccess -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -SnapshotName $SnapshotName  -DurationInSecond $sasExpiryDuration -Access Read
```

and save it to the destination storage account:

```
#Copy the snapshot to the storage account 
Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $storageContainerName -DestContext $destinationContext -DestBlob $destinationVHDFileName
```

More details canbe found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-powershell-sample-copy-snapshot-to-storage-accoun)

Comment: Good idea for another route to take! Do you know how you get the snapshots move to the storageaccount?

Comment: Updated my answer with how to copy images directly to storage account.